# Rails: Dropdown with links to show pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to put a drop down in my navbar where users can click on links to the different stone show pages. With the code I have in now I am getting a NoMethodError private method `each' called for nil:NilClass.

I am pretty sure this private method error is coming up because I am putting this code in my navbar which is in my application.html.erb rather then in the stone model. Could someone point me in the right direction as to where I should define methods for the navbar? Or if there is something else I should be doing instead?

Here is what I have attempted so far:

application.html.erb

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <% @stones.each do |stone| %> 
    <li> <%= link_to stone_url do %>
     <%= stone.name %>
    <% end %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_order
  def each
    @product = Product.all
  end 
  def current_order
    if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
    else
      Order.new
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `.each` on the var `@stones` and not on your controller, views cant call methods from controllers, unless they are helper methods. try to use a before_filter in your controller that will set your `@stones` and remove that `each` method from the controller

Comment: should I put the before_filter in the application_controller or the stone_controller?

Comment: if you are using this navigation trough our in the entire app you should use application_controller for that

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `@stones.each` to `Stone.all.each`.

Because there will be somewhere using var `@stones`, you should not define `@stones` on your `application_controller.rb`.